# How to increase resolution or font size of minimal CentOS install (no GUI)?

Tags: centos, terminal, grub2, display-settings

I've a minimal installation of CentOS 7 on my laptop (dell xps 15 9560). The native resolution of the laptop's screen is 3840x2160, this makes the shell's text very small. How can I increase the size of the text or lower the resolution?

I tried setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` in `/etc/default/grub` and rebuilding the grub config with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`; as suggested in a [similar question](https://superuser.com/a/598390) but it didn't have any effect.